# How to store derived classes of interface in a class getting out concrete type

Tags: c++, interface, polymorphism

I have the following code:

```
class VPersistence {
public:
static VPersistence& get_instance() { return instance; }

// prohibit copy & move
VPersistence(const VPersistence&) = delete;
VPersistence(VPersistence&&) = delete;
VPersistence& operator=(const VPersistence&) = delete;
VPersistence& operator=(VPersistence&&) = delete;

void SetClass(Character* t);
Character* GetClass();
private:
static VPersistence instance;
VPersistence() {}

Character* _character;
};
```

I want to be able to store a Warrior/ Mage/ etc.. they derive from Character. But when calling GetClass() I want it to return the concrete type without specifying what type I want returned, because I already specified it at SetClass(). What are my options? How could I solve this problem?

For context: I have a main menu and there I want to set the playable class, the other scenes/ levels need to call this class to know which concrete Character is playing the game right now.

So what I had earlier was:

```
VPersistence<Warrior> vpersistence;
auto warrior = new Warrior(start_x, start_y, width, height);
warrior->AddComponent(new Game::CameraComponent(800, 600));
vpersistence.SetClass(warrior);
Objects.AddObject(vpersistence.GetClass());
```

My old VPersistence class looked like this:

```
template <class T>
class VPersistence {
public:
void SetClass(T* t);
T* GetClass();
private:
T* _character;
};

template<class T>
inline void VPersistence<T>::SetClass(T* t)
{
static_assert(std::is_base_of<Character, T>::value, "T must derive from 
Character.");
this->_character = t;
}

template<class T>
inline T* VPersistence<T>::GetClass()
{
return this->_character;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear the usage of VPersistence, and the design seems odd at a first look. Trying to give you my 2 cents I believe you should give a look to C++ templates [https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/]

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify

Comment: So your `VPersistence` was already a template class? Then why don't you return `T*` for `GetClass`?

Comment: Do you know all possible character classes while defining your `VPersistence`? Also, do you need to keep your `_character` as the object of particular character class, or maybe you can store base `Character` pointer and have `std::string getCharacterClassName()` method?

Comment: I added the implementation for reference. The problem is, I need to dynamically change the type each run from Warrior to Mage, for instance, how could I change VPersistence<Warrior> to VPersistence<Mage>

Comment: @pptaszni Yes, I know them. I need the whole class, because I need to add it to the scene of the new level. Like as in: Objects.AddObject(warrior);

Comment: How does your `Object.AddObject` work? Why do you need the concrete character type? Can't you do something like `if(dynamic_cast<Warrior*>(characterPointer))` inside `AddObject`?

Comment: I could think of `std::variant<Mage*, Warrior*> _character;` (as pointers, or values if they are copyable) then you can have templated class setter and normal class getter that returns variant and you can check later on, which class is actually stored. But I don't like this solution, it is early stage hacking, not a good design. Would be better to just store the base class ptr and implement all necessary common methods in the base.

Comment: If you talk about a character which can be a `Warrior` and a `Mage`, how about having a `Champion` which derives from both? Then you can `dynamic_cast` into what you need.
If you want to switch characters, then either go with a `getCharacterClassName` as pptaszni suggests or you can use something like the `std::is_same`
Another option is you provide a method like `getCharacterAs<type>()` which does the dynamic cast for you and returns a nullptr in case it is the wrong type